# Why is that if we evaluate this: TRUE AND TRUE ? 'yes' : 'no' is equal to TRUE

Tags: php

Why is that if we evaluate this: `TRUE AND TRUE ? 'yes' : 'no'` is equal to `TRUE` and not equal to `yes`

and when evaluate this: `(TRUE AND TRUE) ? 'yes' : 'no'` is equal to `yes`

and lastly when we try to evaluate: `TRUE && TRUE ? 'yes' : 'no'` is equal to `yes`

is this a php bug or what? TIA :)

Comment: The ?: operator has a higher precedence than the AND operator. That's why you need brackets. Checkout this: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Comment: This is what your code gets evaluated to: `TRUE && (TRUE ? 'yes' : 'no')`. A non-empty string is truthy, hence this is equal to `TRUE && TRUE` which in turn evaluates to `TRUE`.

Comment: I would avoid writing such code to increase readability and decrease confusion. Adding brackets would be the least harmful but avoiding such constructs is best IMHO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Trust the language**. Whatever behaviour you observe happened because that's what your code does. If you see a bug, it's 99.99% percent that it's your fault, and not a bug in PHP.

With this mindset you can make progress.

---

See what *pure reasoning* shows us:

```
TRUE AND TRUE ? 'yes' : 'no'
```

and

```
(TRUE AND TRUE) ? 'yes' : 'no'
```

behave differently.

Because all we did was changing the order of evaluation, that means that the first expression must have parsed as:

```
TRUE AND (TRUE ? 'yes' : 'no')
```

And indeed, `TRUE and 'yes'` is `TRUE`.

---

The rules are sometimes complicated. In this case you have to know the [operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) and how values are [converted to boolean.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting)

The [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) specifically mentions the difference.

> The reason for the two different variations of "and" and "or" operators is that they operate at different precedences. (See Operator Precedence.)

---

In case you're unsure about the precedence order it's best to explicitly mark your intention with parentheses. At least, that's what I do. If it's not obvious to me, it might cause problems to others as well. And of course, you can read the code faster if you don't have to recite the rule. Don't abuse this though, obvious things shouldn't be mentioned in the code, don't increase syntactic noise just because you're lazy to learn the basic rules ;)

---

For a practical viewpoint, it's best to avoid `AND` in your code.

Comment: and how about this one: TRUE && TRUE ? 'yes' : 'no' is equal to 'yes' why is that it is not evaluated like this: TRUE && (TRUE ? 'yes' : 'no') instead it is evaluated (TRUE && TRUE) ? 'yes' : 'no'